# ADF 12c 2nd Application not display 1st Application App modules

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created 2 Applications. App1 (model and view) model contain app module. 1st app jar file add as library in to 2nd Apllication. but in second Application app modules not appear in data control section.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same and it worked fine for mee. See screenhots

1. Make sure you create not just "1st app jar" , but in Deploy Profile you have to choose "ADF Library JAR file" - See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeJGA.png)
2. Just add this jar to the Modul Profile of App2 - See Img2.png
   [image]

As You can see in the Img2.png it does display the App mopdule in data control section[!